# How to Set View To up-down of each other programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm iPhone developer and for setting a UIView to the up-down of each other I'm using this code:

```
UIView * view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 160)];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:view1];

UIView * view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, 160, 160)];
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:view2];

UIView * view3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 160, 160, 160)];
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor pinkColor];
[self.view addSubview:view2];

UIView * view4 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 160, 160, 160)];
view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:view2];
```

But I want to know how to display same views programmatically in Android. My view's frame will not be the same its dynamic.

Actually I am trying to understand how the dynamic layout works in android. In iPhone we have X,Y,Width and Height which we can define for any dynamic view. But I have done some research and I learnt that in android its have Relative layout so we are not able to set X and Y position of the views like in ios.

I have list of the X,Y,Width,And Height in my database and according to the DB I set the size of my Views in my iPhone project.

Now I want to do same in android but my Android developer said that it's not possible bcoz of the relative layout so I want a solution to create same things like iPhone in Android.

For above example I have DB which contain X,Y,Width and Height

```
X     Y   Width   Height
0     0   160     160
160   0   160     160
0    160  160     160
160  160  160     160
```

This is what it look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set like this way  in LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.CENTER);
```

view.addView(button, params);

and in Relative Layout

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
    (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)positiveButton.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 0);
view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: THanx for answer but i think i am not clear with my requirement. I have edited my question plz take look.

Comment: I have added the image for how it should be look like.